# More efficent solution required

Tags: c++, algorithm

Below is the question from one of the online programming contest that I tried for practice.
I have solved it but I was looking for more efficient solution.

**Problem:**
There are n objects numbered from 1 to n from left to right.
Length of i-th object is exactly ai feet.
A group of objects is a non-empty contiguous segment of the line. The size of a group is the number of objects in that group. The strength of a group is the minimum length of an object in that group.
For each x such that 1 ≤ x ≤ n the maximum strength among all groups of size x.

**Input**
The first line of input contains integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 2 × 10^5), the number of objects.
The second line contains n integers separated by space, a1, a2, ..., an (1 ≤ ai ≤ 10^9), lengths of objects.

**Output**
Print n integers in one line. For each x from 1 to n, print the maximum strength among all groups of size x.

**Sample test case:

Input**
10
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 6

**Output**
6 4 4 3 3 2 2 1 1 1

---

**My Solution:**

```
#include <iostream>

int row1[200000];
int row2[200000];
int max[200000];

int main()
{
    int bears;
    int next;
    int *old_row = NULL;
    int *curr_row = NULL;

    std::cin >> bears;
    std::cin >> next;

    row1[0] = next;
    max[0] = next;

    old_row = row1;
    curr_row = row2;

    for(int i = 1; i < bears; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> next;
        curr_row[0] = next;

        if (next > max[0])
        {
            max[0] = next;
        }

        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            curr_row[j] = old_row[j-1] < next ? old_row[j-1] : next;
            if (curr_row[j] > max[j])
            {
                max[j] = curr_row[j];
            }
        }

        int *temp = old_row;
        old_row = curr_row;
        curr_row = temp;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < bears; i++)
    {
        std::cout << max[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the best solution I can think of.
Please suggest an efficient solution.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: consider the objects from longest to shortest and look at their positions.

Comment: This question would be better fit on the Code Review SE site.

Comment: So, you are just sorting a group of integers max to min?  Yeah, there are ways to do that pretty fast - faster than a bubble/insert sort for sure.  Look into various counting/radix sorts to start.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not actually an answer. I just found it interesting to express the solution in the form of Python expression:

```
>>> d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6]
>>> print [max(min(d[i:i+l]) for i in range(len(d)-l+1)) for l in range(1,len(d)+1)]
[6, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Not because of performance but because of compactness.

Answer (score 0):

Not gonna give you the code here in-case you want to devise an implementation yourself. (Ruins the practice that you desire.) but take a look at these:

A Wikipedia article is always nice place to start:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Really good, more indepth explanation: https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/18RadixSort.pdf

This actually shows how to do it, not sure if you wanted that:
http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-radix-sort/

Comment: But sorting doesn't solve the problem ... the relative positions of the numbers matter. Note there is a 5 in the input but no 5 (and an extra 1) in the output.

Comment: Ah, my apologies; I completely missed that. I just saw a sorting problem from largest to smallest. You could probably still use some of the radix formulas to speed it up; it generally is one of the more optimized sorts. (Just modify to apply the specific manipulations required.)